# How to access elements of JSON array in javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsp

I'm currently creating an ArrayList in Java, then running the .toJson function from Google-gson on it:

```
public String statusesToJson(ArrayList<String> statuses){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(statuses);
}
```

Which results in the JSON:

```
[ "u", "u", "u", "u" ]
```

Then in JSP I'm passing it into JavaScript:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">CheckStatus.loaded('<%=model.getPageId() %>', '<%=request.getContextPath() %>', '<%=model.arrayListToJson(model.getStatuses()) %>');</script>
```

Then in the JavaScript I'm parsing it to a JSON array:

```
CheckStatus.statuses = JSON.parse(statuses);
alert(CheckStatus.statuses);
```

This then results in the following output:

```
u, u, u, u
```

The problem is that the following doesn't work and causes my page to not load:

```
alert(CheckStatus.statuses[0]);
```

What's wrong with this?

EDIT:
Loaded Function:

```
loaded : function(guid, context, statuses) {
        CheckStatus.guid = guid;
        CheckStatus.context = context;
        CheckStatus.statuses = JSON.parse(statuses);
        alert(CheckStatus.statuses[0]);

        if(CheckStatus.init == null){
            submitForm('checkStatusForm', CheckStatus.guid);
            CheckStatus.init = true;
        }

        setupForm('checkStatusForm', function(){CheckStatus.validStatus();});

        //CheckStatus.setImages();

        applyCSS3('Check_Status');
    }
```

Valid Status Function:

```
validStatus : function(){
        CheckStatus.params = $('#checkStatusForm').serializeObject();

        if(document.getElementById('regionID').value != "" && document.getElementById('regionAction').value != ""){
            submitForm('checkStatusForm', CheckStatus.guid);
        }else{
            error("Cannot Commit", "You must select an action before attempting to commit.");
        }
    },
```

Setup Form Function:

```
/**
 * Sets up the form to submit when the user presses enter inside an input
 * element. Also calls the callback when the form is submitted, does not
 * actually submit the form.
 * 
 * @param id The id of the form.
 * @param callback The callback to call.
 * @return Nothing.
 */
function setupForm(id, callback) {
    $('#' + id + ' input').keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            $(this).parents('form').submit();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    $('#' + id).submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        callback();
    });
}
```

Submit Form Function:

```
/**
 * Serializes and submits a form.
 * 
 * @param id
 *            The id of the form to submit.
 * @param guid
 *            The guid of the page the form is on to pass to the server.
 * @return nothing.
 */
function submitForm(id, guid) {
    var subTabId = $('#' + id).closest('#tabs > div > div').attr(
            'id'), tabId = $('#' + id).closest('#tabs > div')
            .attr('id'), data = $('#' + id).serializeArray();
    data.push( {
        name : "framework-guid",
        value : guid
    });
    $.ajax( {
        type : 'POST',
        cache : 'false',
        url : '/pasdash-web/' + tr("_", "", tabId.toLowerCase()) + '/' + tr("_", "", subTabId)
                + '.jsp',
        data : data,
        success : function(html) {
            $('#' + subTabId).html(html);
            resourceChanged(tabId, subTabId,
                    $('#' + id + ' input[name="framework_command"]')[0].value,
                    guid);
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            error('Ajax Error', textStatus);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: "I'm parsing it to a JSON array" -> No you're not, you're parsing it _from_ a JSON array to a JavaScript `Array`.

Comment: What exactly does that "loaded" function do?  There's very likely no reason at all for you to have to express the JSON as a string; it's redundant.

Comment: Hmmm....isn't JSON supposed to be name:value pairs? That just looks like a regular old JS array.

Comment: @Diodeus — No, the outer most data structure in a JSON text can be an object or an array.

Comment: Here's the documentation for the loaded function: ` /**
  * Called when the checkstatus tab is loaded and it's DOM is ready.
  */`

Comment: Could you give use the HTML output of that script element, instead of the jsp code?

Comment: I'm looking at the HTML, but I don't see it.  Would it still show up there even though it doesn't output anything to the page?

Comment: You don't need the "language" or the "type" attributes on your `<script>` tags by the way.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to wrap your JSON with strings, that will just force you to have to reparse it. I would try removing those quotes and not calling `JSON.parse`

```
loaded : function(guid, context, statuses) {
    CheckStatus.guid = guid;
    CheckStatus.context = context;
    // Here's the change
    CheckStatus.statuses = statuses;
    alert(CheckStatus.statuses[0]);
```

And change your HTML to be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CheckStatus.loaded('<%=model.getPageId() %>', 
                       '<%=request.getContextPath() %>',
                       // the following line should output something like
                       // ["a", "b"]
                       // which is perfectly valid JavaScript
                       <%=model.arrayListToJson(model.getStatuses()) %>);
</script>
```

Comment: I think I already tried that once and the page still froze. I'll try it again when I get back to work in the morning and see what sort of console output it gives if it doesn't work.

Comment: Alright, so initially that didn't work, as I recalled from the first time I tried it.  However, now that I knew about the browser console I examined that output and saw that the array was null on the initial page load.  I just threw in an if statement to see if it was null before doing anything with it and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write:

```
CheckStatus.loaded('<%=model.getPageId() %>', '<%=request.getContextPath() %>', <%=model.arrayListToJson(model.getStatuses()) %>);
```

**without the quotes** around the last argument.  Then, that "loaded()" function will get the object directly and there'll be no need to call "JSON.parse()".

Comment: Also it makes me really sad to see scriptlets in JSP in 2012.

Comment: Removing the quotes and the JSON.parse(), then calling `alert(CheckStatus.statuses[0]);` still causes the page not to load.

Comment: try removing the quotes but keeping the parse

Comment: Well you're not giving us a lot to work with here, @PseudoPsyche.  That "loaded" function that's called: what exactly does it do?

Comment: It handles the form submissions somehow:

`loaded : function(guid, context, statuses) {
  CheckStatus.guid = guid;
  CheckStatus.context = context;
  CheckStatus.statuses = JSON.parse(statuses);
  alert(CheckStatus.statuses[0]);
  
  if(CheckStatus.init == null){
   submitForm('checkStatusForm', CheckStatus.guid);
   CheckStatus.init = true;
  }
  
  setupForm('checkStatusForm', function(){CheckStatus.validStatus();});

  //CheckStatus.setImages();

  applyCSS3('Check_Status');
 }`

Comment: And this is the validStatus function that setupForm ends up running as a callback:

`validStatus : function(){
  CheckStatus.params = $('#checkStatusForm').serializeObject();
  
  if(document.getElementById('regionID').value != "" && document.getElementById('regionAction').value != ""){
   submitForm('checkStatusForm', CheckStatus.guid);
  }else{
   error("Cannot Commit", "You must select an action before attempting to commit.");
  }
 },`

Comment: If something's making your page not load, then there's a JavaScript errror. Do you know what the "console" is?  What browser are you using?

Comment: Also, here are the setupForm and submitForm functions:

Setup:
`function setupForm(id, callback) {
 $('#' + id + ' input').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
   $(this).parents('form').submit();
   e.preventDefault();
  }
 });
 $('#' + id).submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  callback();
 });
}`

Comment: You should be editing that code into the question, not into comments. THey're illegible as comments.

Comment: Ok, I've added all the code to the OP.

Oh, I just noticed the console tab in FireBug, I assume that's the console you're referring to and not Eclipse's console?  Hang on, I'll run it again and check the output.

Comment: Without the quotes I get: JSON.parse: unexpected character.  With the quotes I get: object is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

length = object.length,

Comment: Don't call "JSON.parse" when you're not quoting it in the function call. The point is that JSON notation is already valid JavaScript; there's no reason to turn it into a string and then parse it again.

Comment: If I don't call JSON.parse, and then try to access elements of the array like: alert(CheckStatus.statuses[0]), then it just gets the character present in the String at that index.

Comment: @PseudoPsyche you don't need to call `JSON.parse` if you don't put quotes around your scriptlet that fetches the JSON

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of the result of JSON.parse (). Seems to me that it is a string and not an array. Maybe a pair of quotes somewhere that should not be there?